# Prove if any group has order 9, then it is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I not getting how to start with this.I have completed Lagrange theorem.

Comment: what does lagrange theorem say?

Comment: Step 1: Prove that a group of order $p^n$ has a nontrivial center. Step 2: Prove that a group with cyclic center is abelian.

Comment: @AlexG. : Do you really mean a group with cyclic center is abelian??

Comment: Oops, no. Rather, if $G/Z$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian

Comment: What is "this"? The post doesn't seem to state a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elementary approach to proving that a group of order 9 is Abelian](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795102/elementary-approach-to-proving-that-a-group-of-order-9-is-abelian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that any group of order $p^2$ where $p$ is a prime is abelian. In your case $9=3^2$, hence the group is abelian.

For more details see the link [Any group of order prime square is abelian](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Order_Prime_Squared_is_Abelian)

Answer (score 3):

A group of order $p^2$ with p a prime is always commutative :

Because the cardinal is a power of $p$, the centre of $G$ is non trivial : indeed, $|Z(G)|\equiv 0 [p]$, so cannot be $1$.

Then, if $G$ was not abelian, you would have $Z(G)\subset G$ not to be an equality. Like $|Z(G)|$ divides $|G|$, it is $1$, $p$, or $p^2$. It is not $1$ because the centre is non trivial, and it is not $p^2$, because $G$ is not abelian.

So $Z(G)$ has p elements. Then you take $g\in G\setminus Z(G)$. The subgroup generated par $G$ and $g$, is of cardinal greater than $p+1$, and dividing $p^2$, so it is $G$.

Then, every element $y$ of $G$ is $y=z.g^k$, where $z\in Z(G)$, and $k\in \mathbb Z$. But so $yg=zg^{k+1}=zgg^k=gzg^k=gy$ for all $y$. Then $g\in Z(G)$, and that is absurd.

So $G$ has to be abelian.