# Doubt regarding "Elementary approach to proving that a group of order 9 is Abelian"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to understand the solution of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795102/elementary-approach-to-proving-that-a-group-of-order-9-is-abelian) problem . I am unable to understand why :

> If $yx=x^2y$, then $yxy^{-1}=x^2$. This means that $y^3xy^{-3}=x^8 $

It seems like I am missing something silly , but why is this true ?

Comment: @Alvin Lepik No, this is not true. We do not suppose that the group is abelian. This is what we need to prove.

Comment: $(ab)^c = (ab)(ab) \cdots (ab) $ Then , why is it so , @Alvin Lepik

Comment: @Mark , if we raise to power 3 we get : $y x^3 y^{-1} = x^6 $ but then what ?

Comment: My comment was wrong. I deleted it.

Comment: Ditto what Mark said.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Shaun , IThanks for reminding ! I wanted to accept it immediately but the website told me to wait 4 minutes , after which I forgot to mark it as the answer Lol :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
y^3xy^{-3}&=y^2(yxy^{-1})y^{-2}\\
&=y^2x^2y^{-2}\\
&=y(yx^2y^{-1})y^{-1}\\
&=y(yxy^{-1})^2y^{-1}\\
&=y(x^2)^2y^{-1}\\
&=yx^4y^{-1}\\
&=(yxy^{-1})^4\\
&=(x^2)^4\\
&=x^8
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 So this did involve a bit of manipulation !