# If $(G,\cdot)$ is a group of order 9, then it's Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Show that if $(G,\cdot)$ is a group of order 9, then it's Abelian.

How to show this when you are given Lagrange's theorem and class equation?

Well, Lagrange's theorem basically states the following: $| G|/| H| = [G:H]$ when $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I don't see how to use this theorem on my problem?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795102/elementary-approach-to-proving-that-a-group-of-order-9-is-abelian) is another duplicate.

Comment: @lulu thanks, the second link seems to be what I am looking for.